# facebook app auth status

Tags: javascript, facebook

i am thinking of a browser extension for facebook.
now in the app details -- advanced, should i choose a Web app or a Desktop app.
and how do i authenticate?

i am going to be making this in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you'd want this to be a Web app.  You will use the JavaScript SDK provided by Facebook.  In `FB.Connect` you will find the `FB.Facebook.init` function, which takes an `apiKey` among other things to authenticate itself with Facebook.  You will be provided with an API key once you register your intent to create a Facebook app.

An example app can be found on the JavaScript Client Library [Wiki](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/JavaScript_Client_Library), along with links to documentation.